# Alarm Manager didn't Triggger to Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm going to build an Application with Alarm feature to remind the patients to take medicine on time.

But current issue is the alarm manager didn't trigger on the XiaoMi phone, and  it work on the samsung note 4 in Android 6.0. And before implement the code to my project, I had create a new project and using the same code to test it. In the new project the code work perfectly as long as the Autostart permission has grant. The alarm will trigger on time, and even restart the phone, the boot receiver will also work recreate the alarm, but it only didn't work on my application.

And now below is my code.

OnAlarmReceiver.java

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "Received wake up from alarm manager.");

        long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

        WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowid);
        context.startService(i);

    }
}
```

ReminderManager.java

```
public class ReminderManager {

    private Context mContext;
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public ReminderManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {

        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId);

        int broadcastID = Integer.parseInt(taskId+""+when.getTime().getDate()+""+when.getTime().getYear()+""+taskId);
        broadcastID = (int)when.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("Alarm when : "+ when.getTimeInMillis());

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, broadcastID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        System.out.println("Alarm Set ID : "+broadcastID);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac= new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            mAlarmManager.setAlarmClock(ac, pi);
            System.out.println("Android 6.0 Marshmallow and above.");

        }else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            System.out.println("Android 4.4 Kikkat and above.");
        }else{
            mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            System.out.println("Android 4.3 Jelly Bean and below.");
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Forgot to mention, i had already register the .OnAlarmReceiver in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver" />
```

**My main issue is with same code it work on the new project i had create to do testing, but didn't work on the my main project.**

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you register the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: @nickfriske  yah, i had register the receiver in the manifest already

Answer (score 0):

Register `OnAlarmReceiver` in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: yah, i had register the receiver in the manifest already, but it didn't work

Comment: Check your phone. Try others alarm app on Play store. Factory reset if it does not work

Comment: as what i say on top there, the same code will work on the new project i created to do testing

Answer (score 0):

```
 <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```